# What is the maximum duration my parents could stay here in the UK if I sponsored their visit?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens

What is the maximum duration my parents could stay here in the UK if I sponsored their visit (from India)? I would like for them to stay for at least 3 months. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

As visitors, your parents would normally be allowed to stay for up to 6 months, although there's always the possibility that they'd be admitted for less time.

From the "India" tag I'm guessing they're Indian citizens, in which case they'll need [Standard Visitor Visas](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).

The most likely difficulty when applying for the visa is making a convincing case that they're not going to stay in the UK indefinitely. Showing that have ties to their home country (work, relatives, a home) is the best way to do this.

Citizens Advice have [a useful page](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/visas-family-and-friends/getting-a-visa-for-family-and-friends-to-visit-the-uk/) on helping someone apply for a visa to visit you.

Comment: The big difficulty is going to be making a case that they can be away from home for six months but have strong ties to their home that ensure they will go back at the end of their visit.